# Histogram Normalization

Tags: opencv, histogram

I am trying to apply histogram normalization to create a dense color histogram.

1. Split the channels into R, G, B
2. Normalize the individual histogram
3. Merge

I think that this is the normal step perhaps if I am wrong please let me know. Now,

for a rainbow image as shown below I get [image] I get max of 255 for all 3 channel and 0 as min. Using the formula for

Pixel - Min / (Max - min) * 255

I will get the same image as the original one back. What is the critical step that I am missing. Please advise me.Thank you!
REf: http://www.roborealm.com/help/Normalize.php.. I used this reference

Answer (score 0):

White = (255,255,255). Black = (0,0,0). So your program finds the white background, and the black line in the bottom right.

Remove the white and change it to black. Then make your program ignore black.

Comment: ignore black as in the minimum becomes 1.

Comment: At what pixel coordinates do you get that value?

Comment: actually i meant that i set black pixel with value (0,0,0) to (1,1,1)

Answer (score 0):

images having white and black pixels cannot be normalized as such. your formula is giving you the same value. try ignoring all white and black pixels and normalize the pixels one by one.

as i see here you have a well distributed image for all channels already, so normalizing this one may not work well anyways..

Comment: "try ignoring all white and black pixels and normalize the pixels one by one." sorry for little knowlegde but you meant I should not change anything on the white and black pixels..

Comment: I attempted some work on this as per your advice I posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17287958/color-histogram-normalization.. Can you please have a look and let me know