# Color Histogram Normalization

Tags: opencv, image-processing, histogram

I asked this question yesterday on this thread found here: 
[Histogram Normalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271872/histogram-normalization/17285027?noredirect=1#17285027).

However, I tried using some ideas i got in link to perform Normalization on a image and i got the following result. Here I normalize all the pixel to 50% except the black and white pixels. 
The formula i used is:`(pixel - min) / (max - min) * 127`

```
pixel = (float)src.at<uchar>(j,i);


if (pixel == 255)
{
    img.at<uchar>(j,i) = pixel;
}

if (pixel == 0)
{
    img.at<uchar>(j,i) = pixel;
}

/*if (min == 0 || max == 0 || (max - min == 0))
{
    img.at<uchar>(j,i) = pixel;
}
else
{*/
    normal__ = ((pixel - min)/(max - min)) * ( 127);
    img.at<uchar>(j,i) = normal__;
//}

}
```

Results:

```
RED PIXEL: MIN = 0 MAX = 253
GREEN PIXEL: MIN = 0 MAX = 254
BLUE PIXEL: MIN = 0 MAX = 255
```

Image before Normalization
[image]

After Normalization using above formula:
[image]

Now, I am confirming if my steps are correct. Thank you..:)

Answer (score 0):

Since the statements

```
  normal__ = ((pixel - min)/(max - min)) * ( 127);
   img.at<uchar>(j,i) = normal__;
```

are not in an if-else statement, they get applied to the black and white pixels too. Is that fine?

Comment: When i place it in the else statement it gets distorted pixels over some region.. Wonder why is that

Comment: I guess it is because of leaving out just 0 and 255 as black and white levels. The resulting normalization function is not smooth. Not all of the white regions on the car will be 255 pixel level.
Your current normalization function spreads the pixel valus in the range 0-127, whereas the normal range for images is 0-255. This why the image is darker. A normalization function usually intends to do the opposite; if the pixels are in a smaller range, it will disperse the values between 0-255. You can take a low contrast image, and use 255 instead of 127. That should work.

Comment: Oh i see my mistake there. One more question like for a image if for each channel R G B, i get the min and max pixel value. If min = 0 and Max = 255 than i will get the same channel as the input. IS this normal?

Comment: I tried the idea you told and it works fine with low contract image

Comment: Your current algorithm will leave the image unchanged if min=0 and max=255. Such cases need a more complicated algorithm.
With histogram equalization, the algorithm will distribute pixels along the histogram. For example, it will try to get 25% of the pixels within the brightness range 0-63. So there will be better results even in such cases. Depending on your need, you can improve your algorithm.